# May I copy some paragraphs of other writers as examples?

Tags: copyright, copying

I’m a Spain-based writing tutor and I’m currently working on a writing guide. I’d like to quote well known writers as examples, which means include some paragraphs of such authors. Is there any problem to do so with USA writers? May I include a couple of paragraphs of, say, Stephen King or Jonathan Franzen? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE! This seems like a legal question, so [Law.SE](https://law.stackexchange.com/) may be more applicable, but I think this would be on-topic here as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to publish it, you will need permission.  This does not fall under "fair use" because you are quoting them about writing, not while writing about the works you are quoting.

(I am not a lawyer, but this is the advice I have always gotten.)